# puppeteer show result in screenshot but cant get value of that result

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

after click on the search button, the puppeteer take a screenshot but I can't get the element's value

here is my code

```
await page.$eval('#textInputSelector',(el, licenceInfo) =>
                                     (el.value = licenceInfo),licenceInfo) 
               
const searchBtn = await page.$x('//*[@id="searchBtnXPath"]')
await searchBtn[0].click()

await page.waitFor(4000);

console.log(await page.$eval('#selector1', el => el.innerText));

await makeScreenShot(page, screenPath, { fullPage: true })
```

and the result is (red box)

[result's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B12Bd.jpg)

and its HTML code output

```html
  <div> 
    <span id="#selector1" >
      Your search returned no results. Please modify your search criteria 
      and try again.
    </span>                               
  </div>
```

and button html code

```html
 <div id="#selector2"> 
      <a id="searchBtnXPath" href="
           javascript:
           __doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnNewSearch','');
           var p = new ProcessLoading();p.showLoading(false);">
        <span>Search</span>
     </a>
 </div>
```

and this is my error

```
Error: failed to find element matching selector "#selector1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
console.log(await page.$eval('body #selector1', el => el.innerHTML));
```